# Is there a way to open Eclipse in a clean build AND restart server at same time?

Tags: eclipse, websphere, galileo

I find myself on startup of my Eclipse environment with a Websphere server that defaults to a normal runtime. Typically I have to restart my server in Debug AND doing a clean build of my application to get it running. Does anyone know if there is a way to default to debug on startup or include "Start Debug"/"Clean build" into a single action?

Answer (score 0):

You can [manually enable debug mode](http://www.mkyong.com/websphere/remote-debugging-with-eclipse-websphere-7/) in your WebSphere server; this should persist across restarts of both eclipse and WebSphere, which will show up in the eclipse server view as already in debug mode.  From there you should just have to publish your application, depending upon your [publishing settings](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user/topics/twpub.html).

[image]